# Why Q.head = Q.tail + 1 represents the queue is full in CLRS

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue

I was reading Elementary Data Structures from CLRS and while reading Queue ADT I came across this:

> When  Q.head = Q.tail + 1  , the queue is full, and if we attempt to enqueue an
>   element, then the queue overflows.

Is it always true? because if Q.tail equals Q.length then we set Q.tail = 1 according to the text. Therefore if we completely fill the Queue then Q.tail  and Q.head will be pointing to the same position (index 1) and the above condition shall not hold. What am I missing here? Please point out where am I misinterpreting the text. Thanks in advance.

Here Attribute Q.head  indexes, or points to, queue's head. The attribute Q.tail indexes the next location at which a newly arriving element will be inserted into the queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Wrap around feature of queue:**

You need to understand the fact that location 1 in the array immediately follows location n in circular order.
For example 
[image]

Predecessor of element g at index 1 is f at index 11. Tail pointer always points to the next empty location where new element will be inserted, in enqueue operation, before inserting element we check for overflow condition, if Q.tail +1 = Q.head, it means tail is reached at head location, means no free space, means queue is full.

**NOTE: (n-1) length queue can be created with the array of length n.**

Comment: I had the same question on reading that line. I still do not understand why the algorithm checks for the overflow condition the way it does? Q.tail + 1 = Q.head means that Q.tail position is empty and available.

Comment: That means we can only enqueue 'i', and 'j'; after 'j' is enqueued, tail would points to 5. When we proceed to enqueue 'k', we do the overflow check and find tail+1 == 6. Then we throw error. So 5 will be empty. That's why CLRS says using array size of n you can only store n-1 elements.

Comment: @mkc at first it was confusing for me as well, but then I remembered that because we want to only ever have [n - 1] elements for an array of n elements, the position in the insert order next to head is expected to be empty. 

The same understanding helps explains why when Q.head = 1 and Q.tail = Q.length, then the queue is considered full as well

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the same paragraph in CLRS,

> to implement a queue of at most n-1 elements using an array Q[1...n].

which means one position is left. It's for checking if the queue is full. If we use all the array positions, the empty queue condition and full queue condition would be the same, which is Q.head=Q.tail.  @siddstuff has explained the wrap around feature, Q.head = Q.tail+1 means there is only one empty position left, so the queue is full.

Answer (score 4):

It's been been six years but none of these answers point out the fact that in circular buffers, there is no clean way to differentiate the case where the buffer full vs empty cases. In both cases `head = tail`.

Most workarounds hinder readability and introduce complexities, so when implementing circular buffers, we make a few assumptions that solve this problem and maintain simplicity.

- We deliberately use only `N-1` elements in the `N` element buffer.
- When `head = tail` it means the buffer empty.
- `tail + 1 = head` means the buffer full.

[Here is a good read](https://embedjournal.com/implementing-circular-buffer-embedded-c/) on implementing circular buffers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have your book, but from how I would implement a cyclic buffer: The condition `head = tail + 1` means that if an element is inserted then tail is increased by one and then `tail = head`. But if head is equal to tail the queue is considered empty.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting this point : "The condition means that if an element is inserted and tail is increased by one then tail = head." Could you please elaborate

Comment: When you insert an element, `tail` is incremented. So if you have `head = tail + 1`, you insert an element, you got `head = tail`, since this is supposed to be the empty state, you can't insert an element when `head = tail + 1`, so it means the queue is full.

Comment: @zakinster why not? queue can be full only when there are no empty slots left. That means, it is possible to enter an item into the tail position when head and tail are not in the same position.

Comment: Ok, I got it, the idea is to keep one slot empty to accommodate the fact that the head and tail should not point to the same location when queue is full: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, the reason you can't allow the array to be completely filled is because then there would be no way to determine if it's full or empty.

To check if it's empty `Q.head = Q.tails` is the only way, for you can't rely on something like `Q.head = 1 and Q.tails = 1` since the queue could be empty in any position, not just position 1.

That's the reason a queue created with an array of length `n` can only hold up to `n-1` elements, and to check if it's full we do `Q.tail + 1 = Q.head` (or `(Q.tail + 1) mod n` to account for the case where `Q.tail` points at position `n`).

Answer (score 0):

When the queue is implemented with an array of `Q[1..n]`, It can hold up to `n-1` elements. But the condition for `is_full` must be `[head == tail+1]` mod n not just `head == tail+1`.

Answer (score 0):

All this confusion arises from the fact that CLRS takes array indices starting at 1 and not zero.

So, we have to implement queue of capacity n-1 using n elements because, we we have n elements and we do n%n we will get zero, and there is no such index as per CLRS. So, we restrict to n-1 capacity, so that modulo always gives atleast 1.