# Where should rear point in queue data structure

Tags: data-structures, queue, fifo, abstract-data-type

Where should rear point in a `queue`:

1. Place where new element WILL BE inserted.
2. Place where last element of the queue resides.

According to my research, I got both above cases as answers.

Comment: You got both answers because both are right. It's a matter of choice. There's no clear "better" choice. I like having it point to the place where the new item will be inserted, because that doubles as the count. For example, when the queue is empty the tail index is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say go with the `TailPointer` pointing towards the last element that was added instead of the empty slot where you'd add the new element. I have a few reasons for that:

- To get the last element you can directly get the value at `TailPointer` which is more like the name. Instead of going with a `TailPointer - 1`.
- In case you have an `Array` as a backing DataStore for your `Queue`, it'll be natural to check `tailPointer == dataStore.Length - 1` (since 0 based indexing is most common)
- Also you would be wrapping your data to initial indexes (the one's before the Head Pointer) in case you `DeQueue` your data. (refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399414/3766231) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75315/whats-the-advantage-of-two-pointers-linked-list-implementation-of-queue-versus))
- If no data is in the Queue, you can simply set the TailPointer to `-1`.